# Task Form if approved and rejected go to different url in Office 365 environment

Tags: list, development, document-library, office-365, spservices

I am trying to Redirect the task form after approving or rejecting it will be directing to the task list but i should redirect it to the home page of the site.

Comment: Does adding `&Source=<url of home page>` to the query string of the task form work?